# Is there a way to strip out white space from excel sheet name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to import an excel file and a particular sheet within the file called 'Cover sheet'. How can I insure that if the sheet name is misspelt, e.g. 'Cover sheet ' (there is an extra space there), then the correct sheet is still selected?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
df.pd.read_excel('../blabla/bla.xlsx', sheetname='Cover sheet')
```

Comment: Is the problem only consists one or multiple spaces in the end or there are more scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

A simple space removal is:

```
text = "english language"
text_without_spaces = text.replace(" ", "")
print(text_without_spaces)
```

Then you can try importing the one with space and the one without space and handle errors accordingly.

If you want a broader approach for this kind of use case I would advise using (wisely) difflib's SequenceMatcher.
SequenceMatcher will compare two strings and return you a similarity coefficient from 0 (totally different) to 1 (identical).

Here's an example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

original_text = "english language"
test1_text = "english language"
test2_text = "Englishlanguage"

print(similar(original_text, test1_text))
print(similar(original_text, test2_text))
```

**Output**

```
1.0
0.9032258064516129
```

Then you could import the Excel file as a whole and compare the sheets names using the above function and act if the ratio is, for example, > than 0.8:

```
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names()
    if similar(sheet_name, name_to_compare) > 0.8:
        # do something
```

Be sure that you take into account false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but you can get a list of sheets of the excel file and work from there using xlrd

```
import xlrd
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(r'<path_to_your_excel_file>', on_demand=True)
xls.sheet_names()
```